# How can I stop this out of bounds exception in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, indexoutofboundsexception, bluej

Hi I wanted to know how to write up a try and catch block to stop from getting the below error.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

I have this method which takes a sentence and splits it into an ArrayList. I then use that to store values into a hashmap, where index 1 is the key and the words after become the value. I use the below method to split the user input into an array.

private Scanner reader;

```
    /**
     * Create a new InputReader that reads text from the text terminal.
     */
    public InputReader()
    {
        reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getInput() 
    {
        System.out.print("> ");                // print prompt
        String inputLine = reader.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();

        String[] wordArray = inputLine.split(" ");  // split at spaces

        // add words from array into ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String word : wordArray) {
            words.add(word);
        }
        return words;
    }

}
```

and the below method uses the class above to detect user input. So when the user types in write they can write into a hashmap but if they press return before they type in a key and value I get the out of bounds exception. So How can i rewrite the below method to avoid this?

```
 public void start()
    {

        boolean finished = false;


            printWelcome();
            while(!finished) {
                ArrayList<String> input = reader.getInput();

                if(input.contains("shutdown")) {
                    finished = true;
                }

                if (input.contains("load")) {
                    System.out.println();
                    instruct.readAndFill();
                    System.out.println();
                }            

                if (input.contains("write")) {
                    String key = input.get(1);
                    String value = "";
                    for(int i=2; i<input.size(); i++) {
                        value = value + " " + input.get(i);
                    }
                    instruct.mapWrite(key, value);
                }
            } 
            instructorGoodBye();
        }
```

Sorry if i wasn't clear enough, or if my code is not up to scratch i have only been learning java for about 2 months now.

Comment: A container (array, list, etc) of size 1 has only one element, at index ZERO.  Attempting to use index 1 will get an out of bounds error.  Please use a debugger (Eclipse, NetBeans, Idea) to step through your code and stop on the exception so you can see what is happening.  If you do not know how to do this, find a tutorial on the web and learn before doing anything else.  Using a debugger is fundamental to learning coding and you will be severely limited until you do so.

Comment: Your problem is probably with this line: `String key = input.get(1);`, for this to succeed your list would need to have two elements in it, and it looks like it only has one.

Comment: @nickb HI Nick basically if (input.contains("write")) is seen as the 1st element, basically if the user types in write key value on one line it is fine but if they hit return after write then the error happens. I am not sure how to rewrite it in order to avoid that.

Comment: Runtime exceptions like `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or `NullPointerException` are an indication of incorrect program logic. Don't try to fix them with a `try...catch`. Instead, correct the program so that it doesn't provide bad indexes or invalid arguments etc.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks Bluej does come with a debugger, i will look at it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> basically if the user types in write key value on one line it is fine but if they hit return after write then the error happens.

So, fundamentally what you are missing is **error checking**. Your program is taking input from a user, and assuming it is valid. **This is always a bad idea**.

Instead, you should validate what you get from the user. One way you can do this, for your "write" block, is to make sure the elements you expect to be there, are actually there.

To start, I would rewrite your loop as follows:

```
while(!finished) {
    List<String> input = reader.getInput();
    if(input.size() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must specify command, one of 'shutdown', 'load', 'write'");
    }

    final String command = input.remove(0).toLowerCase();
    // TODO: Make sure command is one of the valid commands!
```

Note the changes:

1. Assigning to `List` instead of `ArrayList` is just a good general practice.
2. Checking the input to make sure it has more than zero elements
3. Taking the first element, since we don't want to have to do `List.contains()`. Consider the input `garbage garbage garbage write`, clearly we don't want this to invoke the "write" command, it should be considered invalid input.

Finally, we use this to rewrite the conditions on executing our commands:

```
if(command.equals("write")) {
    // Make sure the user put the right stuff in here
    // Since we removed the command from the input already, just make sure what is left is 
    if(input.size() <= 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must specify correct data");
    }
    String key = input.remove(0);
    String value = String.join(" ", input); // Java 8
    instruct.mapWrite(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going to make sure I fully understand the changes as well as the code before I implement it.

Comment: Hi it still crashes the system if the user presses enter, I don't want the system to crash if the user presses enter, instead tells them what is wrong and let's them try again.

Comment: @user5647516 - This is where you have to enhance your debugging skills. Ask yourself, why is it crashing? Use the stack trace to your advantage. You know that pressing enter is an invalid input, so you need to write a check for that condition, and if that check succeeds, you tell the user what they did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error for below part of the code..

```
if (input.contains("write")) {
                    String key = input.get(1);// here is the problem..
                    String value = "";
                    for(int i=2; i<input.size(); i++) {
                        value = value + " " + input.get(i);
                    }
                    instruct.mapWrite(key, value);
                }
```

in the line 2 of this code snippet. **you are accessing a value by using the index. Now just imagine you just enter a single word in the console. so the arraylist you will get from the getInput() method will have the size of 1. So.. in the arraylist the word will be placed on 0th position.(that is the first position) but you are accessing the value on second position.. Thats gives you a index out of bond exception..**

Comment: thanks @kaushik what would be the best way to rewrite this? Should I do a try and catch block?

Comment: using a try catch block will not be effective. you can use checking kind of things. If the size of the list is 1 then you can print a error msg..

Answer (score 0):

basically the fix was simpler than throwing a new exception and using a try and catch block. All I had to do was slightly change the logic and just use and if else statement.

```
  if (input.contains("write")) {    
                    if(input.size() >=2) {

                        String key = input.get(1);                   
                        String value = "";
                        for(int i=2; i<input.size(); i++) {
                            value = value + " " + input.get(i);
                        }
                        mapWrite(key, value);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Please type in the key & value after write all on line");
                    }

                }
```

From what I have learned from java so far, is that the best solutions are normally always normally the simplest. Thanks for all the help, everyone who commented and tried to help me basically helped me come up with the idea.